# New window relative position to the previous one in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, window

I'm not sure how this works precisely, but in Windows Explorer, often when a new window is opened, it's automatically positioned relative to the previous one. The default setting seems to be about 20 pixels lower and 20 pixels to the right.

Then if you open again a new window, it also positions itself +20/+20 pixels from the previous one. And so on, indefinitely.

Is there a way to change that setting? Changing any of those values, making them positive or negative, etc.

Ideally I'd like a solution without an external app. For example a registry hack, etc.

Lastly, I'd like to know the solution (or solutions) for three operating systems: Windows 7 (deprecated, I know), Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

First of this is for Windows 10.  Windows 11 (22H2) has an all new File Explorer with tabs.

Second for File Explorer in Windows 10, open File Explorer, File, New Window.  It open as you say in your question.  Move the second Window to a new position.   Now close the second Window.  Open a new Window and it opens where you closed it.

So to a certain extent, what you want works. I am fairly sure the effect will not survive a restart.

Natively that is the way File Explorer and many Office / Windows Apps work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.

First, I know what you are describing, but that is not what I'm saying.
I'm talking about opening a new window, that automatically opens about +20/+20 pixels from the previous one.
Then if you open a new window, it opens again at about +20/+20 pixels from the previous one.
And so on, indefinitely.

Second, I am looking for a permanent solution, hence my idea of a registry hack.

Third, I'd like to know the solution (or solutions) for three operating systems : Win 7 (deprecated, I know), Win 10 and Win 11.

Thanks again!

Comment: @JoseHidalgo - Windows has no functionality like that.

Comment: Windows has many Apps and uses the same positioning for all of them. Windows File explorer is not unique here.  As @Ramhound notes, there is no such Windows functionality as you describe, so what I describes works to a certain extent (not surviving a restart)

Comment: Do you mean that such numerical values are hardcoded by the system and there is no way on Earth to find them? That would be disappointing.

Comment: And as I noted (and since Windows 10 is on the down slope), Windows 11 is quite different again. Tabs do not offset at all.  Microsoft is also removing sections in their code to ensure everyone has the same code. You may view this as disappointing.  I just adapt.

Comment: @JoseHidalgo - I am aware of no such capability to open a new file explorer windows based on the relative location of another file explorer window. What you describe is Windows just stacking an multiple instances of an application's window, which has existed for decades,

Comment: Yes, I'm glad we're on the same page. Windows is indeed stacking multiple instances of Explorer windows. But my question remains: Windows stacking seems to have default X/Y offset values. I wonder where those values are coded and if there is a way to change them, that's all.

Comment: No. There are many Windows Apps using this method, and there is no spot for coding positioning for all these apps.

Comment: Thank you all. Like I said, that's disappointing. Hardcoding is rarely a good thing. Question solved (or rather, unsolved).

Comment: My question does provide an answer of what can (and cannot) be done and what is coming in Windows 11 which I use. Hopefully you are able to find it at least helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of registry hack, there is not one to perform the configuration you're requesting. Although the registry is used to reference a great many static variables, unless your program has been specifically configured to reference and store window locations in the registry... it's not a default Windows setting. For example, notepad has a well defined location variable stored in the registry.

However, if you can edit the programming of your referenced application, then this is the solution you're looking for:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210104-00/?p=104656

If such a setting would be found in the registry, it may be found on or near here:
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell`

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will execute once the hotkey
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
is entered.
Modify the values of the following variables as
required: STARTX, STARTY, DELTAX, DELTAY.

```
STARTX := 50       ; x offset of first explorer window
STARTY := 100      ; y offset of first explorer window
DELTAX := 100      ; x offset between successive explorer windows (can be negative)
DELTAY := 200      ; y offset between successive explorer windows (can be negative)
lastHWND = 0
lastX := lastY := 0

~#e::
    Sleep, 1000                        ; wait for one second
    hwnd := WinExist("A")              ; get active window id (hwnd)
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %hwnd%  ; check that this is indeed explorer
    If (class != "CabinetWClass") return
    if (hwnd = lastHWND) return        ; return if this explorer instance was already done
    lastHWND = %hwnd%
    WinGet, count, Count , ahk_class CabinetWClass   ; find how many explorer instances are running
    if (count = 1) {
        newX := STARTX                 ; this is the first explorer
        newY := STARTY
    } else {
        newX := lastX + DELTAX         ; this is an additional explorer
        newY := lastY + DELTAY
    }
    WinMove, ahk_id %hwnd%, , %newX%, %newY%         ; move explorer window
    lastX := newX                                    ; remember used x,y coordinates
    lastY := newY
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)